# Error on creating an android project using Cordova and Sencha Touch 2

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, sencha-touch-2

I am unable to create an android project using cordova in command line. I have followed the following steps and while executing this command "cordova platform add android", I get the following error.

Also, I have downloaded the android SDK files and kept it in a separate folder, and mentioned its path (platform-tools and tools) in the system variables. The Project folder is being created, but could not specify the platform as android. PLEASE HELP !! It would be very helpful if someone explains building an android app using cordova (apart from CORDOVA DOCUMENTATION) easily under few steps. Thanks in advance.

Steps followed:

1. npm install -g cordova
2. cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
3. cd hello
4. cordova platform add android

Error received:

" Please install Android target "android-19"
  Hint-Run "android" from your command line to open the SDK manager "

Comment: Run the command 'android' from your cmd and it will open up a SDK manager window. From there download the "Android SDK tools" and "Android SDK platform-tools".

Answer (score 1):

If you're building an app with Sencha Touch, then you need to use Sencha Cmd to add cordova to your project. First, [download](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) from the Sencha website. Then, assuming you've already created your Sencha Touch project, switch to your Sencha Touch project directory and do the following from the command line:

*Add a cordova project to your Sencha Touch project*

```
sencha cordova init
```

*Add a platform to your cordova project*

```
cd cordova
cordova platform add android
```

*Change back to the Sencha Touch directory and build and run*

```
cd ..
sencha app build -r native
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to create a Sencha Touch 2 app with cordova support for packaging.

1. Once you have installed Sencha CMD and downloaded the Sencha Touch 2 SDK, run the following:

   sencha -sdk [path to sencha sdk] generate app [name of app] [root folder for your app]

sencha cmd will create a folder for you if you have not created one yourself)

2. From inside the newly created folder, run the following to initiate cordova (you can replace cordova with phonegap and it should work fine):
   sencha cordova init
3. A folder named 'cordova' will be created. From inside this folder, run the following to add android platform:
   cordova platform add android
   (keep in mind that the latest Android SDK must be downloaded and that you have the 'tools' and 'platform-tools' folders in your path. You can check this by running the command 'android' from the same terminal tab in which you're running sencha commands)
4. Go back to the root folder of your app, edit the 'cordova.local.properties' file and set the platform to 'android'.
5. From inside the root folder of your app, run the following to build an aPK:
   sencha app build native
6. For me, the apk file is found under /cordova/platform/android/ant-build/

This APK should install and work fine.